# can I generate VC++ 64bit application on my 32bit XP machine?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have read few pages about 32-bit and 64-bit application but I am still not clear if I can build a **VC++ application** which target on 64-bit machine with my **VS2008** on my 32bit XP machine?
Those pages are : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s(v=VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s(v=VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

They said by using **64-bit compiler**, we can build an application to run on 64-bit machine. But I cannot find anywhere tells me if I can install that 64-bit compiler on my **32bit XP machine**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you install the 64-bit compilers for C++ (custom install required) then you'll get *three* compilers in the vc\bin directory:

- vc\bin\cl.exe: a 32-bit compiler that generates 32-bit machine code
- vc\bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe: a 32-bit compiler that generates 64-bit machine code
- vc\bin\amd64\cl.exe: a 64-bit compiler that generates 64-bit machine code.

The 2nd compiler is the default choice for a x64 project, it has no trouble running on a 32-bit install of XP.  Do note however that you have no way to actually test or debug the generated program.  Which makes it only practical in a build server scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no reason not to be able to install a 64 bit compiler. The thing what you want to do is called cross compilation, and is done regurarly on embedded platforms (lacking keyboard, even display some times). You might need to download the compiler separately though.

You could set it there: [image: settings pane]

Answer (score 0):

The very first note in your second link says:

"64-bit tools are not available on Visual C++ Express by default. To enable 64-bit tools on Visual C++ Express, install the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) in addition to Visual C++ Express. Otherwise, an error occurs when you attempt to configure a project to target a 64-bit platform using Visual C++ Express."

Am I missing something, or does this answer your question?